# How can preserve the types for a mapped object in Typescript

Tags: typescript

If I have a dictionary object such as:

```
const x = {
  foo: {inner: 3},
  bar: {inner: 'hi'},
};
```

Where there is an inner property with varying type (string and number here for example).

Then I would like to map this to a structure which looks like:

```
const y = {
  foo: 3,
  bar: 'hi',
};
```

**However I'd like to be able to do this automatically without losing any type information.** Is this possible in Typescript?

I can *almost* get there with lodash:

```
import { mapValues } from 'lodash';
const y: Y = mapValues(x, (z) => z.inner);
```

However this ends up taking the union of all types in the dictionary, with the type signature:

```
const y: {
    foo: string | number;
    bar: string | number;
}
```

Rather than the desired:

```
const y: {
  foo: number;
  bar: string;
};
```

Comment: You wrote `const y = {
  inner: 3,
  inner: 'hi',
};`; is that really what you mean?

Comment: Oops you're right it should be: `const y = { foo: 3, bar: 'hi', };`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
type Wrapped<T> = {[K in keyof T]: {inner: T[K]}};

function unwrap<T>(x: Wrapped<T>): T {
  // (the implementation here is not the point)
  return _.mapValues(x as any, z => z.inner) as T;
}

const y = unwrap(x);
```

Reference: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html (the very last paragraph)

Comment: I'm still trying to figure out how this works, but it works! You're a shiny god!

Comment: This also appears to work without the `as any` and without the `as T`.